# Regex to find duplicate phases

Tags: regex

I got a chance to get a regex to find all the duplicate phases at: https://www.regextester.com/93564
The regex used there is /(\W|^)(.+)\s\2/

I don't understand why this could work. I know (\W|^) would make sure the matching is starting with non-word character or the start of a string. (\W|^)(.+)\s would end with a whitespace. But I don't understand why after we put them together it can find duplicate phases. Could anyone please explain this to me?

Also if I want to specify only get duplicate phases after certain character/string, what should I add to it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want `:test test` to count as a match you could change `\W` to `\s` to match a whitespace character instead.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for reminding me this.

Answer (score 0):

The `\2` in your Regex is helping to find duplicates. It's like mentioning if the second capture group occurs again, then that entire portion is a match.

To get duplicate phrases after certain character / string - for instance `a` - just add it to the start of expression like `/(?<=a)(\W|^)(.+)\s\2/` where `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind (may not be supported in all browsers) which ignores whatever is there inside it.